# Expo React Native sudden fontFamily is not a system font error, not using fonts

Tags: react-native, expo

Hi Guys I suddenly got this error message

```
fontFamily "Ubuntu_700Bold" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\expo-font\build\Font.js:29:16 in processFontFamily
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3681:14 in diffProperties
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:3692:40 in diffProperties
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:4015:28 in createInstance
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:14706:39 in completeWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18123:27 in completeUnitOfWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18096:29 in performUnitOfWork
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18013:38 in workLoopSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17977:18 in renderRootSync
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17674:33 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at [native code]:null in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5321:31 in runWithPriority$argument_1
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:653:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5316:21 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5304:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17718:28 in batchedUpdates$1
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2492:29 in batchedUpdates
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2638:16 in _receiveRootNodeIDEvent
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2767:27 in receiveTouches
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I am not using the font anywhere at all, last package I added was socket.io and then after building the app I got this error which is pretty annoying. This is my package.json dependencies:

```
{
 "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps": "^8.2.0-beta1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "expo": "^41.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-facebook": "~11.0.5",
    "expo-font": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.2.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~9.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.5.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-rapi-ui": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.15.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.0.1"
  }
```

I already tried to remove the node_modules, the yarn.lock, to use expo -r c. Any idea?
Thanks in advance